# Excel sorting many columns after each other - macro to loop through?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, macros

I have a matrix which matches peptide in row 1 to proteins in column A (996 rows, 346 columns). When a peptide is in a protein the field says TRUE, fields without a match are blank. I want to do a simple sort by column one after the other after the other ... but don't want to do custom sort by column 345 times manually...

Is there a way of doing it in an automated fashion?
[example of sorted matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6EZ4.jpg)

Your advice on how to do this is highly appreciated.
Thanks you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function in VB to do it for you.

Add the developer tab if not already enabled

Click 'record macro' and then sort the first column or two, then click ;stop recording'

Hit Alt-F11 to see the recorded data in the VB window.

Now for the fun part. Put a loop around the bit you need to repeat 346 times. Replace references to the column with an offset function that references the iteration number. Make sure the spreadsheet is saved and then test the code.

If you don't know how to write VB functions, do a bit of reading about VB loops in Excel and then come back to this. If you are doing a lot of analysis in Excel then you'll need to know how eventually anyway.